# How to increase capacity of String in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to assign huge string to the variable ( higher than 65 000 characters ). due to this I've prepared the following VBA code:

```
Dim cell As Range, str As String * 200: str = "( "
Dim val As String * 200

For Each cell In rawData.UsedRange.Cells
    val = cell.Value
    str = str & Chr(34) & val & Chr(34) & ", "
    Debug.print str, val
Next
```

But the console returns always "( " even thought val contains string

Can anyone tell me why VBA does not join this text ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Remove  the `* 200` what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: If I remove it then the program is executing even 5hours.

Comment: because for the string object I can assign only 65000 characters _ according to documentation )

Comment: And I need to assign around 600 000

Comment: @vba_user Did you consider using a string array?.. 600k characters is kinda massive.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by a string array ? sorry for question but I am not an expert :-)

Comment: The question is: What do you actually want to do once you have that 600k string? I think you are up the wrong tree.

Comment: I want to insert data into DB using VBA. So i am going through the excel sheet using for loop and adding new elements to the one string. Once the loop is over I am executing my query. And it works but for around 500 rows and I have to insert around 20 000

Comment: Then you should consider to run a query for each row. And the limit for a string (variable length) in VBA is `2^31 = ~2 billion` characters, so this is not your issue.

Comment: well I don't want to execute 20 000 queries at once. If I remove  that line then everything works okay, that's why I assumed this is because of String

Comment: If you remove **which** line? Please be a bit more detailed. And what's wrong with running a query for each line? *"I don't want"* cannot be a reason.

Comment: I don't know what you're sending to sql but I'm going to assume it's either an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`. Instead of executing each individual query you could use XML to do all 20,000 say in one query.

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, I need to execute INSERT query. by "each line" I understood that you recommend to insert each single line in one request ( so I'd send around 20 000 requests ). Can you please clarify how to use XML to do this ? is there any tutorial ?

Comment: if you wrap it around a transaction it really won't take very long to execute 20,000 inserts - perhaps 5 minutes. It would certainly be quicker than using vb to concatenate a 600k string!